# Is there a way send a file stored on a remote URL from the server to the client efficiently?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, http, stream

**Context:**

This is my first time working with files using Nodejs.
I am making a Youtube video downloader for personal use.
In the frontend I have multiple buttons representing a video quality, each button has attached to it a URL where the video can be found for the specified quality.

When a specific button is pressed, the function 'download' from 'client.js' is being called and gets passed the URL representing the button and a filename.

My first try was to create a write stream to the public folder of my app, and after the download was finished, get the video from the path in the frontend, but it was taking too long and it was really inefficient for big files.

The current way it works is mostly the same as the other one, but this method is even slower than the other method I used.

How can I make the download more efficient?

For example when the user presses a button, the download to right away.

**client.js**

```
const download = async (url, filename) => {
    const error  = document.querySelector(".error")
    const status = document.querySelector(".status")

    try {
        status.textContent = "Downloading ..."

        const response       = await axios.get("/download", {params: {url, filename}})
        window.location.href = response.request.responseURL

        error.textContent  = ""
        status.textContent = "Download Complete"
    }
    catch(e) {
        error.textContent  = "Cannot Download The Data!"
        status.textContent = ""
    }
}
```

**server.js**

```
app.get('/download', async (request, response) => {
    try {
        const URL = request.query.url
        const filename = request.query.filename
    
        response.attachment(filename)

        const { data } = await axios.get(URL, { responseType: 'stream' })

        data.pipe(response)
    }
    catch (e) {
        return response.status(404).send({error: "Url Not Found!"})
    }
})
```

Comment: hello, if you have a url that can download a video directly .. why don't you just redirect the user to the url via a simple <a> tag.. and omit the need for a server at all .. if the link has a downloadable file the browser will automatically start downloading it once it is clicked.. let me know if this works

Comment: I tried it, but it was just redirecting the page to the specified URL without actually downloading the file to the user because of the cross origin stuff. Thank you for responding!